# Spring Data Mongo Check if there is data or record

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I would like to check if there is a data or records like: Check if an employee have leave data or not.

Using spring data mongo, what is the best way to do this?

I checked, it seems I cannot do something like `.limit(1)` or `findBy...Limit`.

Only thing I have in mind now is: `findFirstBy...` or `countBy...`

I want the faster one, the table I will be checking with have more or less 1M data.

Is there a better way to check this? (findFirst vs countBy vs BETTER)?

By the way, in my bigger tables... I have some index. Is it possible with spring data mongodb to get the count of the records while using an index?

Find First vs Count By:

With my almost 3M data and comparing the speed between `findFirstBy` vs `countBy`, `findFirstBy` is much faster than `countBy`. An example with the said collection... find first executes (0.3s) while count by executes (3s). This is just a sample execution difference but the idea is... find first is faster than count by.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify which index to use. Mongo will by default use the index based on the matching columns. 
Make sure you have an index on the leave column to speed up the query.

> findFirst

- Will return the first matching instance, so will typically be the fastest as it will only scan the index and return as soon as it finds any match

> limit(1)

- will be almost as fast as it will exit as soon as it finds a match. If you add sorting criteria, it will slow down as it needs to fetch the correct element based on sorting order, not just any element

> count

- will usually take the longest as it needs to scan the whole collection, not just lookup. If you use a sparseIndex on leave here, the count operation will speed up significantly

To understand these operations better, try running an [Explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/) on the queries.

**Note - the query performance is independent of the client invoking it.**